# Not enough memory when running wordcloud

Tags: python, pandas, word-cloud

I want to create a word cloud with the [dataset on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/sobhanmoosavi/us-accidents). However, I'm having issues with WordCloud giving me the error Not enough memory available to compute the word cloud.

The code that I have:

```
# Loading The Data
filename = "../input/us-accidents/US_Accidents_June20.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

```
# Import package and it's set of stopwords
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator

# Create stopword list
stopwords = set(STOPWORDS) 
stopwords.update(["due",'accident'])
```

```
# Combine all description into one big text
df['Description']=str(df['Description'])
text = ' '.join(df['Description'])
```

```
# Create and generate a word cloud image:
wordcloud = WordCloud(
    background_color='white',
    max_font_size=50, 
    max_words=50,
    stopwords=stopwords
).generate(text)

# Display the generated image:
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Is it because the 'text' is too large to be handled? Is there any other way to combine the description into one big text so that the word_cloud is able to handle it?

Comment: How big is the text? What if you take a sample? Does it work? Like text[:100]

Comment: @Tasos There are 2533317856 words after combining all description into one big text. I am thinking if I could remove all stopwords in the 'text' first to make it a little bit smaller.

Comment: just to be sure, before you do anything else, on the 3rd code block, after the line you set the text, add this text = text[:10000]. With this, you will be sure that this is the problem. Always work with a sample and when you are sure, try to the whole dataset

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have done it. As you said in the comments, you have a corpus with 250m words. This is probably enormous for your machine to handle and create a wordcloud. You should try to minimize your data to the most valuable words. One idea is to keep only words with high frequency.

P.S. I haven't tested the code, so forgive me if there is any syntax error.

```
filename = "../input/us-accidents/US_Accidents_June20.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filename)

# Import package and it's set of stopwords
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator

# Create stopword list
stopwords = set(STOPWORDS) 
stopwords.update(["due",'accident'])

# Create a variable with all the text from Description column
tokens = df['Description'].str.split().tolist()

# Create a counter for each work and it's frequency
from collections import Counter
Counter = Counter(tokens ) 

# Keep top X words with higher frequency
most_occur = Counter.most_common(1000) 

text = ' '.join([x[0] for x in most_occur])

# Create and generate a word cloud image:
wordcloud = WordCloud(
    background_color='white',
    max_font_size=50, 
    max_words=50,
    stopwords=stopwords
).generate(text)

# Display the generated image:
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```